# Reshaping a pandas dataframe without a true index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

I've been trying to construct a dataframe of regression outputs for the past few weeks, and I've gotten most of the way there. I am now trying to reshape it around certain keywords in a column that as far as I can tell is not callable.

A simplified version of my dataframe looks like:

```
?           coef pval  se   rsq
Intercept   1    0     .1   .1
Cash        2    0.2   .05  .1
Food        2    0.05  .2   .1
Intercept   3    0     .1   .2
Cash        1    0.01  .2   .2
Food        2    0.3   .1   .2
Zone        1    0.4   .3   .2
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
                (1)      (2)
Intercept coef   1        3
Intercept pval   0        0
Intercept se     0.1      0.1
Cash coef        2        1
Cash pval        0.2      0.01
Cash se          0.05     0.2
Food coef        2        2
Food pval        0.05     0.3
Food se          0.2      0.1
Zone coef        NaN      1
Zone pval        NaN      0.4
Zone se          NaN      0.3
rsq              0.1      0.2
```

So far I've tried several approaches, with the promising being reshaping using r-squared (rsq) as an index -> `RegTable = RegTable.pivot(index='rsq', columns=['pval', 'coef', 'robust_se'])`

This, however, returns the error `ValueError: all arrays must be same length`. Some research makes me think this is because as of right now, `zone = NaN` is represented by the regression simply not having a zone row, but I'm not sure how to fix it. In addition, I've been unable to figure out how to call the column I identified as "?" using PANDAS - it's not labeled in the CSV  output. In addition, this approach seems problematic as in the off chance that two regressions have the same r-squared, it will either end up throwing a new errror or averaging each value, neither of which are exactly desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df.set_index(['rsq','?']).stack().unstack([0]).T\
  .reset_index().T.rename_axis([None,None])\
  .rename(columns={0:'(1)',1:'(2)'})\
  .sort_index()
```

Where df:

```
           ?  coef  pval    se  rsq
0  Intercept     1  0.00  0.10  0.1
1       Cash     2  0.20  0.05  0.1
2       Food     2  0.05  0.20  0.1
3  Intercept     3  0.00  0.10  0.2
4       Cash     1  0.01  0.20  0.2
5       Food     2  0.30  0.10  0.2
6       Zone     1  0.40  0.30  0.2
```

Output:

```
                 (1)   (2)
Cash      coef  2.00  1.00
          pval  0.20  0.01
          se    0.05  0.20
Food      coef  2.00  2.00
          pval  0.05  0.30
          se    0.20  0.10
Intercept coef  1.00  3.00
          pval  0.00  0.00
          se    0.10  0.10
Zone      coef   NaN  1.00
          pval   NaN  0.40
          se     NaN  0.30
rsq             0.10  0.20
```

Comment: Nice, but you forgot the rsq row at the end.

Comment: It is the top row. I guess I could sort it.

Comment: Ooh nvm. Didn't see it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  Okay, I sorted it. :)

Comment: This problem was fun sort of like playing Judo with a dataframe.

Comment: Yeah it took me a while to come up with the answer. Pity this question hasn't gotten any attention. +1

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you explain the logic of stack-unstack-reset_index? Your solution works wonderfully like last time but I'd love to get a better understanding of why it does so.

Comment: A trick is to run the statement piece by piece.   First just run df.set-index... then add stack, which stacks the columns vertical at a new row index level.  then I unstack the first index (level=0) which is 'rsq' and make that data in to the column index.  Run T, transpose so I can move that column index into a row index, next I reset_index to move that index in to a column.  And then T transpose everything back and do some house keeping with renaming and sorting.  Just run the statement piece by piece until you get to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The intuition behind this solution is to slice the dataframe into two roughly equal parts. The assumption here is that you only have two sets of data points, so this becomes manageable.

```
print(df)

           coef  pval    se  rsq
Intercept     1  0.00  0.10  0.1
Cash          2  0.20  0.05  0.1
Food          2  0.05  0.20  0.1
Intercept     3  0.00  0.10  0.2
Cash          1  0.01  0.20  0.2
Food          2  0.30  0.10  0.2
Zone          1  0.40  0.30  0.2


df_ = df.reset_index().iloc[:, :-1]

df2 = df_.iloc[df_['index'].drop_duplicates(keep='first').to_frame().index]
df1 = df_.iloc[df_['index'].drop_duplicates(keep='last')\
                 .to_frame().index.difference(df2.index)]
```

Once this is done, each piece must be stacked and then concatenated along the first axis.

```
out = pd.concat([df1.set_index('index').stack(),\
                 df2.set_index('index').stack()], 1)
out.append(pd.DataFrame([df.rsq.unique()], index=[('rsq', '')]))
out.columns = ['1', '2']

print(out) 

                   1     2
index                     
Cash      coef  1.00  2.00
          pval  0.01  0.20
          se    0.20  0.05
Food      coef  2.00  2.00
          pval  0.30  0.05
          se    0.10  0.20
Intercept coef  3.00  1.00
          pval  0.00  0.00
          se    0.10  0.10
Zone      coef   NaN  1.00
          pval   NaN  0.40
          se     NaN  0.30
rsq             0.10  0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly eccentric way to do this without splitting up into two data frames.

This solution renames the indices to keep track of the regression they belong to, adding in `NaN` when there's a missing field (as is the case for `Zone`).
Then `groupby`, `stack`, and split the column of lists into `(1)` and `(2)` columns (although it's generalized to handle as many regressions as occur in the data).

With `df` as:

```
            coef pval  se   rsq
Intercept   1    0     .1   .1
Cash        2    0.2   .05  .1
Food        2    0.05  .2   .1
Intercept   3    0     .1   .2
Cash        1    0.01  .2   .2
Food        2    0.3   .1   .2
Zone        1    0.4   .3   .2
```

Rename index values as `Intercept0`, `Intercept1`, etc:

```
measures = df.index.unique()
found = {m:0 for m in measures}

for i, name in enumerate(df.index):
    if np.max(list(found.values())) > found[name]+1:
        df.loc["{}{}".format(name, found[name])] = np.nan
        found[name] += 1
    df.index.values[i] = "{}{}".format(name, found[name])
    found[name] += 1

df
            coef  pval    se  rsq
Intercept0   1.0  0.00  0.10  0.1
Cash0        2.0  0.20  0.05  0.1
Food0        2.0  0.05  0.20  0.1
Intercept1   3.0  0.00  0.10  0.2
Cash1        1.0  0.01  0.20  0.2
Food1        2.0  0.30  0.10  0.2
Zone1        1.0  0.40  0.30  0.2
Zone0        NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Now arrange rows so that elements from each regression are grouped together.  (This is mainly necessary to get the `NaN` rows in the right spot.)

```
order_by_reg = sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: ''.join(reversed(x)))
df = df.loc[order_by_reg]

df
            coef  pval    se  rsq
Food0        2.0  0.05  0.20  0.1
Zone0        NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
Cash0        2.0  0.20  0.05  0.1
Intercept0   1.0  0.00  0.10  0.1
Food1        2.0  0.30  0.10  0.2
Zone1        1.0  0.40  0.30  0.2
Cash1        1.0  0.01  0.20  0.2
Intercept1   3.0  0.00  0.10  0.2
```

Finally, `groupby`, `stack`, and split the resulting column of lists with `apply(pd.Series)`:

```
gb = (df.groupby(lambda x: x[:-1])
        .agg(lambda x: list(x))
        .stack()
        .apply(lambda pair: pd.Series({"({})".format(i):el for i, el in enumerate(pair)})))

gb
                 (0)   (1)
Cash      coef  2.00  1.00
          pval  0.20  0.01
          se    0.05  0.20
          rsq   0.10  0.20
Food      coef  2.00  2.00
          pval  0.05  0.30
          se    0.20  0.10
          rsq   0.10  0.20
Intercept coef  1.00  3.00
          pval  0.00  0.00
          se    0.10  0.10
          rsq   0.10  0.20
Zone      coef   NaN  1.00
          pval   NaN  0.40
          se     NaN  0.30
          rsq    NaN  0.20
```